# Trying to run a R script within a container

Tags: r, bash, batch-processing, slurm, singularity-container

I am trying to run a tool called LINDA with singularity. I am struggling to understand how I can run a R script within the container. So far I am running the command below with slurm but it says there is no such file or directory for `SCRIPT_R`, given my path is good I am suspecting another issue is within my command but can't figure out what it is so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=linda
#SBATCH --output=./log/linda.out
#SBATCH --error=./log/linda.err
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=10
#SBATCH --mem=40G

WD="/my/working/directory"

LINDA_SINGULARITY_IMG="/directory/to/linda/image/linda_latest.sif"
SCRIPT_R=${WD}"/LINDA_script.R"

srun singularity run --cleanenv --bind ${WD}:/home ${LINDA_SINGULARITY_IMG} Rscript SCRIPT_R
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by editing the last line like this.

```
srun singularity run --cleanenv --bind ${WD}:/home ${LINDA_SINGULARITY_IMG} Rscript ${SCRIPT_R}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?